# Partial Update JSON Object using specific key instead of objectID in Algolia

Tags: c#, json, algolia

it's my understanding that to use `PartialUpdateObject` in Algolia, I need to know the `objectID`. [Source](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/partial-update-objects/)

However, in my situation, I do not directly know the `objectID` right off the bat. Let me explain...

I have a music site where an artist can submit music and this JSON filled with song info gets stored into an index in Algolia. Now the artist can also update their profile (to change their artist name and so on). I have two separate indices. One called `Song`, which contains all song information, and `Artist` which contains artist information. When the artist edits his profile to change his artist name, I am trying to make this change reflect across his `Artist` account JSON and all the songs that were uploaded by him/her. If the JSON wasn't updated on the song side, it would still display his/her old name...not good!

Here's what the `Artist` JSON looks like:

```
{
  "AccountInfoID": 94,
  "AccountType": "Artist",
  "DisplayName": "Unlike Pluto",
  "ImageURL": "https://ucarecdn.com/81abba2d-7966-48ac-abab-79a2ecc97811/",
  "UserID": "",
  "objectID": "94"
}
```

Here is what the `Song` JSON looks like. Also note how the one constant between the two json files is the `AccountInfoID`, this links the song to the artist, in this case Unlike Pluto. The `objectID` for `Song` is different. And if I were to upload another song, all the following values would be different except `AccountInfoID` (just to clarify):

```
{
  "ApprovalFL": true,
  "FreeFL": true,
  "LicenseFL": true,
  "AccountInfoID": 94,
  "AlbumID": 117,
  "SongID": 105,
  "BPM": 92,
  "AccountImageURL": "https://ucarecdn.com/81abba2d-7966-48ac-abab-79a2ecc97811/",
  "AccountType": "Artist",
  "AlbumName": "Let It Bleed",
  "Artist": "Unlike Pluto",
  "FeaturedArtist": "Cristina Gatti",
  "ImageURL": "https://ucarecdn.com/d60c9302-eacf-4050-920d-9d54ce93cd46/",
  "iTunesURL": null,
  "LabelName": "Lowly Palace",
  "Title": "Let It Bleed",
  "URL": "https://ucarecdn.com/b75e6e30-7082-49e5-b5d5-93d23e74af21/",
  "UserID": "",
  "UploadDate": "2017-12-16T01:55:22.81",
  "Duration": "2017-12-16T00:03:20",
  "objectID": "105"
}
```

To update the Artist JSON, it's no big deal:

```
dynamic registerArtistObjs = new JObject();
registerArtistObjs.DisplayName = accountInfo.DisplayName;
registerArtistObjs.ImageURL = accountInfo.ImageURL;
registerArtistObjs.objectID = accountInfo.AccountInfoID;
var artistIndexHelper = HttpContext.Application.Get("ArtistIndexHelper") as IndexHelper<ArtistAlgoliaModel>;
artistIndexHelper.PartialUpdateObject(registerArtistObjs);
```

However, the song update is trickier as I need to be able to find all songs that were uploaded by that artist. So as mentioned above, I would need to find all songs with `AccountInfoID: 94` so that I could get the `objectID` and update `Artist` in the song JSON. What is the best approach to doing that or is there an easier way that I am missing?

Here's where I'm at with the code to update the Artist name in the Song index, but I have no clue on how to obtain all the `objectID` values from the Song index that contain, for example, `AccountInfo: 94`:

```
dynamic registerSongObjs = new JObject();
registerSongObjs.Artist = accountInfo.DisplayName;
registerSongObjs.objectID = ??????????Possibly Multiple values?????????
var songIndexHelper = HttpContext.Application.Get("SongIndexHelper") as IndexHelper<SongAlgoliaModel>;
songIndexHelper.PartialUpdateObject(registerSongObjs);
```

Comment: @mjwills hey again, it did...sorta, I found a similar way (using your third method in our original question that helped). I'll mark that one as correct for you. Any thoughts on this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by doing the following:

```
dynamic registerSongObjs = new JObject();
var songs = EntityDataAccess.GetSongsByAccountInfoID(accountInfo.AccountInfoID);
                    foreach (var item in songs)
                    {
                        registerSongObjs.Artist = accountInfo.DisplayName;
                        registerSongObjs.objectID = item.SongID;
                        songIndexHelper.PartialUpdateObject(registerSongObjs);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you "need to be able to find all songs that were uploaded by that artist".

If you keep track of this (I assume your website must rely on some kind of database?), then when an artist is updated, you could fetch all the relevant songID for that artist, and from that infer the list of object you need to update on algolia's end.